# Where are located Bing Translator downloaded language packs files?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, language-translation, language-packs, bing-translator-api

I have a windows 8.1 and I downloaded "Bing Translator" using Store Apps.
Then I have downloaded language packs using "Bing Translator" in order to use the translator as offline.
And it works just fine when internet connection is disabled.
Each language packs file size was approximately 125mb to download.
After download processes and install process there was written 252mb on some language pack.
It seems like installing processes doubles language packs file size.

Anyway I need to know where actually those 125mb files are?
Or even where those 252mb files are located?

I found where actually "Bing Translator" exe file is located:
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.BingTranslator_1.8.2.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
I found it using a task manager:
In a list of processes there was a process called "Translator.exe", after right click on that menu appears and then clicking "Open file location".

But in this directory there is only 24.0 MB information.
There are not downloaded language packs.
Where are they?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a deeper look into what a program is doing you should check out [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Add an include filter for the process name containing *Bing* and you should see all the accesses to the file system and the registry.

If you dig through these messages you'll should find the answer.

My first gues would be that they are located somewhere within %AppData% or %LocalAppData% (Just enter this within an explorer window including the percent signs).